# Select quoted data from query without referencing a table?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I've got a tool that uses LINQ-to-SQL and sometimes I need just one row of text data that I've provided.  In the past I've done something like this:

```
results = (from x in [tablename] select new {myValue1 = "TextValue1", myValue2 = "TextValue2"}).Distinct();
```

But that requires at least one row in [tablename], which is no longer something I can rely on.

EDIT:
Better example to know why I need to do this; I need this query (which is all I can edit in my program) to return everything in "results" and to be ordered correctly:

```
results = from z in (
 from x in [tablename]
 select new 
 {
  myValue1 = "TextValue1",
  myValue2 = "TextValue2"
 }
).Union(
 from y in [tablename]
 select new 
 {
  y.myValue1,
  y.myValue2
 }
)
orderby z.myValue1,z.myValue2
select new 
{
 z.myValue1,
 z.myValue2
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in SQL Server? Can't you just create the result in memory? I can't see the value of doing this without a better example.

Comment: I'm attempting to Union together tables in my LINQ query to data like this.  The program I'm using only allows me to edit the LINQ query so I need to gather and limit my results in this one statement.

Comment: So you always want a hardcoded `Result` to be at the beginning of your list of results that are returned in your `IQueryable<Result>`?

Comment: Chris: Yes, what's going on is I'm allowed to edit what comes after "Results =" and then "Results" is returned in the function.  This code is compiled "on the fly" and not compiled with the main program (the main program is what compiles this code), thus my inability to edit anything except what "Results" is equal to. (Not that any of this is really important to my question)

Comment: This approach is going to return bad results because as you can see if you have 100 records in `[tablename]` SQL server will return 100 records with the harcoded text and it will union 100 more records with the actual values in the database; it will return 200 entries.
Why dont you add the harcoded text in your application and sort it outside sql based on a field.

Comment: I left out the .Distinct() in my union of z, so I don't have that problem.  I don't add it outside because I don't have a way of doing so other than to modify the value of "results".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method returns a regular IList, can you just do something like this?

```
var results = new ArrayList();
results.Add(new {myValue1 = "First", myValue2 = "First"});
results.AddRange(myLinqQuery.ToList());
return results;
```

...where `myLinqQuery` is your existing query.

Comment: The `Result` object isn't recognized.  I've tried modifying this to work but can't find anything that compiles.

Comment: @VenerableAgents: This type name depends on what your LINQ query would return.  I was just calling this generically a `Result`.  From your code, it looks like you're returning an anonymous type, but it seems like you could create a type to use here.

Comment: Yes, it's an anyonymous type.  I may have to research creating a type to use, but it will need to be compatible with other LINQ queries because I will need to Join and Union to them.

Comment: @VenerableAgents: What type does your method return?

Comment: Here's what it looks like right before it's compiled:
`public static Func<IDataContext, string, IList> Querycc38fc6c = (dc, sourceConnection) => {
 var results = (
   from x in dc.GetTable<tablename>(sourceConnection)
   select new
            {
    x.myValue1, 
    x.myValue2
            }
         ).Union(
            from y in dc.GetTable<tablename>(sourceConnection)
   select new
            {
    myValue1 = "TextValue1", 
    myValue1 = "TextValue2"
            }
         ).Distinct();
 return results.ToList();
};`

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is add on a "fake" row of data to places in my queries.

Comment: @VenerableAgents: ok.  I edited the answer to do what I think you need.  You seem to just need to return an `IList` of objects.

Answer (score 0):

for one row you can use

> [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx)() // Throws error if no value to return

or

> [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)() // wont throws error if no value to return

```
    results = (from x in [tablename] select new {myValue1 = 
"TextValue1", myValue2 = "TextValue2"}).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That wasn't my question.  I have no trouble if there is data in [tablename].  What I want is the text data even if there is no data in [tablename].  I don't really even need anything from [tablename].